# Using the Image.point() method in PIL to manipulate pixel data

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-manipulation, python-imaging-library

I am using the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to colorize a black and white image with a lookup table that defines the color relationships.  The lookup table is simply a 256-element list of RGB tuples:

```
>>> len(colors)
256
>>> colors[0]
(255, 237, 237)
>>> colors[127]
(50, 196, 33)
>>>
```

My first version used the `getpixel()` and `putpixel()` methods:

```
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            pix = img.getpixel((x,y))
            img.putpixel((x,y), colors[pix[0]])
```

This was horribly slow.  A `profile` report pointed to the `putpixel` and `getpixel` methods as the culprits. A little investigation (i.e, read the docs) and I find "*Note that this method is relatively slow.*" re: `putpixel`.  (*actual runtime*:  53s in `putpixel` and 50s `getpixel` for a 1024x1024 image)

Based on the suggestion in the docs, I used `im.load()` and direct pixel access instead:

```
    pixels = img.load()
    for x in range(w):
        for y in range(h):
            pix = pixels[x, y]
            pixels[x, y] = colors[pix[0]]
```

Processing sped up by an order of magnitude, but is still *slow:* about 3.5s to process a 1024x1024 image.

A more thorough study of the PIL docs seems to indicate `Image.point()` is *exactly* intended for this purpose:

> `im.point(table)` => image
>
> `im.point(function)` => image
>
> Returns a copy of the image where each pixel has been mapped through the given table. The table should contains 256 values per band in the image. If a function is used instead, it should take a single argument. The function is called once for each possible pixel value, and the resulting table is applied to all bands of the image.

I've spent some time hacking around with the interface, but can't quite seem to get it right.  Forgive my ignorance, but PIL's docs are curt and I don't have much image processing experience. I've googled around a bit and turned up a few examples, but nothing that made the usage "click" for me.  Thus, finally, my questions:

- Is `Image.point()` the right tool for this job?
- What format/structure does `Image.point()` expect the table?
- Can someone rough out an example implementation?  Every iteration I've tried so far has ended up with a straight black image.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is Image.point() the right tool for
>   this job?

Yes indeed, `Image.point()` is perfect for this job

> What format/structure does
>   Image.point() expect the table?

You should flatten the list so instead of `[(12, 140, 10), (10, 100, 200), ...]` use:

```
[12, 140, 10, 10, 100, 200, ...]
```

Here is a quick example I just tried:

```
im = im.point(range(256, 0, -1) * 3)
```

[image]
[image]

And by the way, if you need more control over colors and you feel Image.point is not for you you can also use `Image.getdata` and `Image.putdata` to change colors more quickly than both `load` and `putpixel`. It is slower than `Image.point` though.

`Image.getdata` gives you the list of all pixels, modify them and write them back using `Image.putdata`. It is that simple. But try to do it using `Image.point` first.

---

**EDIT**

I made a mistake in the first explanation, I'll explain correctly now:

The color table actually is like this

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...255, 0, 1, 2, 3, ....255, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...255]
```

Each band range next to the other.
To change the color (0, 0, 0) to (10, 100, 10) it need to become like this:

```
[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...255, 100, 1, 2, 3, ....255, 10, 1, 2, 3, ...255]
```

To transform your color list into the right format try this:

```
table = sum(zip(*colors), ())
```

I think my first example should demonstrate the formate for you.

Comment: flatten the list? ok, but how does that work?  I want pixels with value 0 -> (12, 140, 10) and pixels with value 255 -> (254, 237, 220).

Comment: you know, I think this might be The Only Place On the Internet where the expected format of that table is described.  // I just got img.point() working with the lookup table, thanks to your description.  The results aren't exactly what I expected, but I've got enough to hack around on and figure it out.   Thanks so much!

Comment: @J.J., The format is not really obvious. I made a mistake in my first explanation and I fixed it now. I hope I got it right this time. I'm going to sleep so I won't be able to answer questions.

Comment: ah, yes!  like a champ, and in 0.05s runtime inside point()!  thanks, too for the pythonic ways to flatten the lists.  Those techniques alone would've taken me a while to puzzle out.

Comment: If this really IS the format of the color table, then it's of pretty limited use. For the example at hand, it doesn't just change (0,0,0) pixels, it changes any pixel with red = 0, OR green = 0 OR blue = 0. In short, it's only suited for manipulating the bands as three (or four) individual separate data sets, ignorant of the actual color of each pixel.

Comment: @NadiaAlramli why with  tiff RGB image I get im = image_input.point(range(256, 0, -1) * 3)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'int'  ??

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be more typical to `point` on a band-by-band basis like so  (lifted directly from the PIL [tutorial](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/introduction.htm)):

```
# split the image into individual bands
source = im.split()

R, G, B = 0, 1, 2

# select regions where red is less than 100
mask = source[R].point(lambda i: i < 100 and 255)

# process the green band
out = source[G].point(lambda i: i * 0.7)

# paste the processed band back, but only where red was < 100
source[G].paste(out, None, mask)

# build a new multiband image
im = Image.merge(im.mode, source)
```

Comment: the table format makes more sense with a single band, that's for sure.   I may have to use this route in order to handle the alpha channel with a special case...