# Image from array and image using point

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am using Image.point and Image.fromarray to do exactly the same operation on an image, increase the value of all pixels together by the same value. The thing is that i get to absolutelly different images.

using point

```
def getValue(val):
    return math.floor(255*float(val)/100)

def func(i):
    return int(i+getValue(50))

out = img.point(func)
```

using array and numpy

```
arr = np.array(np.asarray(img).astype('float'))
value = math.floor(255*float(50)/100)
arr[...,0] += value
arr[...,1] += value
arr[...,2] += value

out = Image.fromarray(arr.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
```

I am using the same image (a jpg).

the initial image
[image: initial image]

the image with point
[image: using point]

the image with arrays
[image: using arrays]

How can they be so much different?

Comment: You have values greater than 255 in your array, which you then convert to `uint8` ... what do you want those values to become in the image?

Comment: Actually your image looks right, but you've ruined palette (see previous comment). This link is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181292/using-the-image-point-method-in-pil-to-manipulate-pixel-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have values greater than 255 in your array, which you then convert to uint8 ... what do you want those values to become in the image? If you want them to be 255, `clip` them first:

```
out_arr_clip = Image.fromarray(arr.clip(0,255).astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
```

By the way, there's no need to add to each color band separately:

```
arr = np.asarray(img, dtype=float)   # also simplified
value = math.floor(255*float(50)/100)
arr += value                           # the same as doing this in three separate lines
```

If your `value` is different for each band, you can still do this because of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
percentages = np.array([25., 50., 75.])
values = np.floor(255*percentages/100)
arr += values   # the first will be added to the first channel, etc.
```

Comment: @Apostolos Yeah, `clip` is definitely easier, but kudos for solving it and posting your own solution :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me around...I am getting new to this image processing and its the first time i used numpy. Though arr contains alpha channel too and i don't want to alter it. So i have to do it to each band separately, i think i have to that is :)

Comment: @Apostolos Ah, I see; if you want to edit only channels `0,1,2`, then you can still do it in one line!  `arr[...,:3] += value`

Answer (score 1):

Fixxed it :)

Didn't take under consideration getting out of bounds. So i did

```
for i in range(3):
    conditions = [arr[...,i] > 255, arr[...,i] < 0]
    choices = [255, 0]
    arr[...,i] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=arr[...,i]
```

Worked like a charm....:)