# In python, how would I manipulate the RGB values of the pixels in an image from the output of the .point() method from PIL, then print the new image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I mostly don't understand the output that .point() provides, and how I would change the RGB values of each pixel in the image using this output, if this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean [```im.point```](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.point)? ... it returns a complete copy of the image with the pixels modified by its argument.  The example in the docs scales each (RGB) value by 1.2 and adds an offset of 10.

Comment: So then what argument would I use to, say, set each RGB value to 125, 57, and 100, respectively?

Comment: Or is that even possible with these types of arguments?

Comment: The accepted answer to this SO question [Using the Image.point() method in PIL to manipulate pixel data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2181292/2823755) should get you started with the lookup table, otherwise use a function like the example in the docs.