# How to count bright pixels in an image?

Tags: python, count, sum

How do I make this code print the total number of bright pixels that are over 200:

```
from PIL import Image
img = input("File name: ")
img = Image.open(img);
for y in range(img.height):
  for x in range(img.width):
    pixel = img.getpixel((x, y))
    if pixel >= 200:
      print(pixel,"pixels are bright.")
```

Right now it's printing **every** single pixel that is over 200 on new lines, but I just want one line that prints the total like this:

```
File name: slippers.png
121081 pixels are bright.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the pixels before printing:

```
from PIL import Image
img = input("File name: ")
img = Image.open(img);
count = 0
for y in range(img.height):
  for x in range(img.width):
    pixel = img.getpixel((x, y))
    if pixel >= 200:
      count += 1

print(count,"pixels are bright.")
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need loops at all for this. Simply create a mask returning which pixels are above the threshold, and sum the mask.

## With numpy

You just need to convert the `img` from a PIL `Image` to a numpy array, which you can do with `np.array(img)`. Then create a boolean mask for whenever the pixels are above your threshold, `np.array(img) >= 200`. This will create an array of the same size as your image with a `True` or `False` in each pixel location for whether it meets the criteria. Then if you `np.sum()` the resulting image, it will convert `True` to 1 and `False` to 0, so summing will give the total number of pixels which met the criteria. All of this in one line:

```
bright_count = np.sum(np.array(img) >= 200)
```

## Pure PIL

For a purely PIL solution that doesn't use numpy, you can use the `point()` method of the `Image` class. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181292/using-the-image-point-method-in-pil-to-manipulate-pixel-data) for a good discussion of the method. The `point()` method takes in a function which assigns new values to a pixel. Here I've just assigned a value of 1 whenever it's above the threshold. Then I've grabbed just the data from the `Image` type with the `getdata()` method, and summed the data with the Python `sum()` function.

```
bright_count = sum(img.point(lambda pix: 1 if pix>=thresh else 0).getdata())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getcolors() function from PIL image, this function return a list of tuples with colors found in image and the amount of each one. I'm using the following function to return a dictionary with color as key, and counter as value.

```
from PIL import Image

def getcolordict(im):
    w,h = im.size
    colors = im.getcolors(w*h)
    colordict = { x[1]:x[0] for x in colors }
    return colordict

im = Image.open('image.jpg')
colordict = getcolordict(im)

# get the amount of black pixels in image
# in RGB black is 0,0,0
black_pixels_count = colordict.get((0,0,0))

# get the amount of white pixels in image
# in RGB white is 255,255,255
white_pixels_count = colordict.get((255,255,255))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one too (Python 3):

```
from PIL import Image

imgFile = input("File name: ")
img = Image.open(imgFile);
pixels = img.getdata()
total = len(list(filter(lambda i: i >= (200,200,200), pixels)))
print("There are %d bright pixels" % total)
```

You can use the `getdata()` method to take all pixels at once end then you can filter the ones which are above the desired value. In Python 2, you can simply write `i >= 200`.