# Grayscale Heatmap to Color Gradient Heatmap

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to take a set of 256x256px 8-bit grayscale .pngs (with transparency) and convert the grayscale .png to a color .png of the same size, still retaining transparency. The palette I want to use is Zissou1 from the R `wesanderson` package, which I have gotten into a Python dictionary where each key corresponds to a greyscale value and each value a HEX color.

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageColor

### dic = the dictionary containing the palette in format {grayscale pixel value: "HEX COLOR"},
###       created earlier in the script

with Image.open("3.png") as im:
    fin = Image.new("RGBA", im.size)
    px = im.load()
    px1 = fin.load()
    for x in range(0,256):
        for y in range(0,256):
            px1.putpixel(x,y,ImageColor.getcolor(dic[px.getpixel(x,y)[1]],"RGBA"))
    fin.show()
```

I am getting the error:

```
px1.putpixel(x,y,ImageColor.getcolor(dic[px.getpixel(x,y)[1]],"RGBA"))
AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'putpixel'
```

Comment: Instead of `px1.putpixel(x,y,...)` use `px1[x,y]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend on [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72482888/5730279):

#### The lookup as given by PIL

With [`Image.point(lookup_table, mode = 'L')`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point) you can lookup and transpose the colors of your image.

```
lookup_table = ...
with Image.open("3.png") as orig:
    image = orig.point(lookup_table, mode = 'L')
    image.show()
```

To see an example for using the `Image.point` method with the `lookup_table`:

- [Using the Image.point() method in PIL to manipulate pixel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181292/using-the-image-point-method-in-pil-to-manipulate-pixel-data)

#### Your own implementation (fixed with improved naming)

or implement the lookup against `your_dic` yourself:

```
your_dic = ...
with Image.open("3.png") as orig:
    image = colored_from_map(orig, your_dic)
    image.show()
```

with this alternative function (you almost did):

```
def colored_from_map(orig, map_to_color):
    image_in = orig.load()
    image = Image.new("RGBA", im.size)
    image_out = image.load()

    for x in range(0,256):
        for y in range(0,256):
            coords = (x,y)
            greyscale = image_in.getpixel(x,y)[1]
            color_name = map_to_color[greyscale]
            image_out.putpixel(coords, ImageColor.getcolor(color_name,"RGBA"))

    return image
```

#### Preserving the alpha-channel (transparency)

See the [source-code of `ImageColor.getColor()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/ImageColor.html#getcolor)
at the begin and end of its method body:

```
    color, alpha = getrgb(color), 255  # default to no-transparency
    if len(color) == 4:  # if your mapped color has 4th part as alpha-channel
        color, alpha = color[0:3], color[3]  # then use it

    # omitted lines
    else:
        if mode[-1] == "A":  # if the last char of `RGBA` is `A`
            return color + (alpha,)  # then return with added alpha-channel
    return color
```

(comments mine)

So you could simply set the fourth element of the returned color-tuple to the previous value of the original gray-scale image:

```
            greyscale = image_in.getpixel(x,y)[1]  # containing original alpha-channel
            color_name = map_to_color[greyscale]  # name or hex
            mapped_color = ImageColor.getcolor(color_name,"RGB")  # removed the A
            transposed_color = mapped_color[:2] + (greyscale[3],)  # first 3 for RGB + original 4th for alpha-channel (transparency)
            image_out.putpixel(coords, transposed_color)
```

Note: because the A(lpha-channel) is provided from original image, I removed the `A` from the `getColor` invocation's last argument. Technically, you can also remove the slicing from `mapped_color[:2]` to result in `mapped_color + (greyscale[3],)`.

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough response. I have implemented your code to test it, and ran into the following error: `File "/Users/aidan/Documents/recolor.py", line 60, in colored_from_map
    transposed_color = mapped_color[:2] + (greyscale[3],)  # first 3 for RGB + original 4th for alpha-channel (transparency)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. To clarify, as this might be the point of issue--it's less that I want to preserve the transparency of every pixel, so much as that there are some completely transparent pixels in the image that I want to keep fully transparent.

Comment: My current workaround is to just create another index in my lookup table for when the greyscale value is 0--which is when the pixels should be transparent--is to just set the pixel to black--(0,0,0). Perhaps there is some way somewhere to set all pixels that are a specific color (ie (0,0,0) to be transparent somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to PIL's [`PixelAccess.putpixel`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess) method expects the pixel's coordinates to be passed as a (x,y) tuple:

```
px1.putpixel((x,y),ImageColor.getcolor(dic[px.getpixel(x,y)[1]],"RGBA"))
```

Alternatively, consider using the [Image.point](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point) method which takes a look up table similar to the one you already created to map an image based on pixel values.  See the answer at [Using the Image.point() method in PIL to manipulate pixel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181292/using-the-image-point-method-in-pil-to-manipulate-pixel-data) for more details

Comment: @Mark Ransom's suggestion to just avoid the .putpixel and .getpixel commands sort of solved that component, but you are right that Image.point() would probably be better in the long term. I suppose I would just need to convert my dictionary to a list, and then from a list to a flattened list. The main issue with all of this image processing seems to be preserving the transparent pixels of the original image. Do you have any thoughts about that?

Comment: @metamorporpoise the transparency will be the 4th element of the pixel value.  Just read it from the input and preserve it when you write it back.